# how to get information about the device stack from windbg

Tags: windows, device-driver

```
I have a setup in which host is win8 and guest on virtual machine is also win8. 
Running windbg on host and debuggin guest on virtual machine throgh pipe. 
          Now i want to analyse how a device stack is built internally for a keboard. 
 For this when i run 

 "!drvobj kbdclass"

 on windbg it doesnt show up any keyboard device object in guest,Below is the output     
 what i get

 kd> !drvobj kbdclass
 Driver object (862357d0) is for:
 \Driver\kbdclass
 Driver Extension List: (id , addr)

 Device Object list:
 862480e8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plz, Use !devstack extension command.

ex) !devstack 862480e8

!devstack

The !devstack extension displays a formatted view of the device stack associated with a device object.

```
!devstack DeviceObject
```

Parameters

DeviceObject 
Specifies the device object. This can be the hexadecimal address of the DEVICE_OBJECT structure or the name of the device.

DLL
Windows 2000
 Kdextx86.dll

Windows XP and later
 Kdexts.dll

Comment: thanks for the info it really helped.I have One more query like when i do !drvobj kbdclass it gives me                        Device Object list:                                         91fc5b50 8db5d2c0                                                   i,e 2 device objects ,where as i have only one keyborad connected?

Comment: you can research the device object 91fc5b50, 8db5d2c0 . !devobj 91fc5b50, !devobj 8db5d2c0, and then you will see the information of device object.