# How to view a device driver stack?

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, windbg, sysinternals

There is a [picture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/driver-stacks) on the Microsoft site which represent a USB device driver stack (in other word, the list of all drivers which applys for the device work).

[image]

What software shall I use to get this list? Is such soft in the SysInternals? Some people told me that I can get this list via WinDbg or TraceView. Is this true? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: `!devstack` command in windbg; you wont get a graphical representation but it basically reads like a stack trace. [Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890771/how-to-get-information-about-the-device-stack-from-windbg). Note: it's a **device** stack because a single driver might have multiple different devices, so a driver stack is not really meaningful.

Comment: You may post an answer and I will +1 it.